# Quick way to perform a fulltext-search on MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

First of all: i don't need a full-text-search engine, i don't need full-text-search in my code. I have a database with ~2000 tables, and i need to find the table and column in which certain information is stored, for developing purposes. Is there any quick way (maybe an SQL Server Management Studio trick that i should know of) to do this? I think `phpmyadmin` provides such a feature for mysql dbs. At the moment i'm seriously thinking of dumping the database to an `.sql` file and use a text editor to search for the phrases i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. You can select on it - there is a table containing all the field names etc. and you can then do search on that one.

Comment: sorry, i think i wasn't clear. i need to find what table/field/row contains a specific string, so i'm searching for data. unfortunately i don't have a good description of the db schema, so i'm trying to get an idea of the structure by searching for strings that i know do exist somewhere in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way how to do it without dynamic SQL - get list of all tables and their columns from sys.tables and sys.columns (don't forget to add proper schema if you're using them), construct query that checks for the values you're trying to find and stores table and column name in temporary table, place all queries into (temp) table and finally cursor/loop over that table executing all queries.

PS. your idea of dumping everything into *.sql files should work as well, depends on the volume of data.